# How to load a php code every time the page is loaded?

Tags: php, wordpress

I work on a WordPress website. I use mycred plugin so any user has a points balance (points can be used to buy privileges. The php code below can be used to deduct points.

```php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Points penalty' );
```

How can I execute it every time a user visits a specific page ? So for every visit on the page the user lose points (even if he refresh he sould lose points) any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the 'pre_get_posts' action. This action runs EVERY time a user requests or queries something. This is given to you in the $query variable.

```
function deduct_points($query){
    //this is standard practice
    if(!is_main_query()){
        return $query;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    //EXAMPLES
    //custom post type
    if($query->post_type === 'my custom post type') {
        //run your function
        mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Points penalty' );
    }

     //any page or post
     if($query->post_type === 'page' || $query->post_type === 'post'){
         //run your function
         mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Points penalty' );
     }

    //specific page
    if($query->pagename === 'use the page slug here' ){
          //run your function
    }
    //always return the $query
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sjdh_deduct_points', 1);
```

Comment: but i would like to ask how to get he page slug ?

Comment: you could go to the "edit" of the page you want to check the slug, in Gutenberg editor, if you click/hover on the title, you'll see the permalink appear. the slug is last word on the url

Answer (score -1):

Put your code in a function and call that code on a particular page if you have created a page template.

e.g.

```
function user_penalty(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Points penalty' );
}
```

call this function  `user_penalty()` on the page you want.

Comment: Your function is the exact same thing that he has already written, what changes with respect to his request?